# Resizing elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a header that "collapses" on scroll. I pretty much have the functionality set up, however it is "backwards".

Here's a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/M3MnU/5/) showing the concept.

The issue is that I'd like the header to start tall and decrease height as the page is being scrolled (rather than the other way around).

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    

var $myDiv = $('header');   
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

$myDiv.css("height", st );
```

Comment: ...`$myDiv.css("height", 100-st );`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var $myDiv = $('header');   
    var st = $(this).height() - $(this).scrollTop();
    $myDiv.css("height", st );
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/M3MnU/7/)**